# What does avahi-compat-libdns_sd do?

Tags: avahi

I have Bonjour (mDNSResponder - Linux version) up and running on a Ubuntu Box (Host A). I have managed to port Avahi to a new platform. As I see, ./mDNSNetMonitor is able to discover the service published by avahi on say different host, Host B (/etc/avahi/services/myservice.service) . This means that Bonjour is able to discover the service published by Avahi.

My question here is, why do I need avahi-compat-libdns_sd library. In the context of experiment, do I need to port avahi-compat-libdns_sd library also to the new platform (Host B)? Note that Avahi running on Host B is 'Dbus enabled'.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it provides a `dns_sd.h` header file and a backing implementation using [avahi](http://avahi.org/) to provide compability with the [Bonjour SDK](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/dns_discovery_api/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000964) interface. So no, you do not need to also port the `avahi-compat-libdns_sd` part for your experiment.